# Required parameter missing with DoDirectPayment method

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I have one problem with doDirectPayment with paypal, i make one request with params :

- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26 - params set
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> USER → *****
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> PWD → ****
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> VERSION → 119
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> SIGNATURE → ***
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> LOCALECODE → US
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> IPADDRESS → ****
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> PAYMENTACTION → Sale
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> METHOD → DoDirectPayment
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> CREDITCARDTYPE → Visa
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> ACCT → 5200239459741204
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> EXPDATE → 082018
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> CVV2 → 123
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> FIRSTNAME → XXX
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> LASTNAME → XXX
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> ZIP → XXXX
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> CITY → XXX
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> STREET → XXX
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_AMT0 → 50.17
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_TAXAMT0 → 0
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_CURRENCYCODE0 → USD
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_NAME0 → Description
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> AMT → 50.17
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> ITEMAMT → 50.17
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> TAXAMT → 0
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> NOSHIPPING → 1
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   └──> Fin
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26 - result var
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> TIMESTAMP → 2014-12-08T11:28:26Z
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> CORRELATIONID → xxxx
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> ACK → Failure
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> VERSION → 119
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> BUILD → 14107150
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_ERRORCODE0 → 81100
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_SHORTMESSAGE0 → Missing Parameter
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_LONGMESSAGE0 → OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   ├──> L_SEVERITYCODE0 → Error
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   └──> Fin
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26 - current method
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   └──> DoDirectPayment
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26 - access url api
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   └──> [dev] https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26 - api version
- 2560Ko  34612Ko 11:28:26   └──> 119

But i don't understand why i have this error « OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing » if someone can explain to me ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that looks odd is L_CURRENCYCODE0 (which I don't see as a valid field in the docs) rather than CURRENCYCODE (which is an optional field). I'm guessing PayPal may be stopping their parsing at the unknown fieldname.

Try removing the L_CURRENCYCODE0, and if that fails try removing all the L_ fields to see if that's related to what is tripping you up.